# Android apk created with unity3d does not open on some phones

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

The aplication of my augmented Realty project with Unity3d is not working on some android phones. Works on Samsung Galaxy s5 and Galaxy s10 phone. and I've tried it on many phones like this, but it doesn't work well on Huawei p20 and Samsung Note8. Anybody know how to solve this? I'm sorry for my bad english..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please clarify your **specific problem** or **add additional details** to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. The best way to find out what's causing the crash is by going to the terminal/command prompt and type in "adb logcat", ther you'll probably find what's causing the crash